# Different Coordinate System in GeoJSON data

Tags: geojson

I just started trying to use some open data from the USDA (I'm a front end developer, so I'm not too familiar with how to work with data that hasn't in a fairly straight forward format yet), but I'm not sure what these coordinates are under geometry->rings (they're not lat/lng). I was wondering if anyone could tell me what sort of coordinate system they're using so I can figure out how to convert them. All points should be within Colorado. Thanks!

http://gis.ers.usda.gov/arcgis/rest/services/foodaccess/MapServer/2/query?where=&text=Colorado&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&f=pjson

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a possible answer to your question here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9442/arcgis-coordinate-system

So, the coordinates you received in a format like

```
...
"geometry": {
 "rings": [
  [
   [
    -11804245.4265,     // easting
    4495129.5014000013  // northing
   ],
   [
    -11804198.783199999,
    4488979.7647999972
   ], ...
```

appear to be "Eastings" and "Norhings", coordinates given in **meters**, based on a Mercator like projection (in this case: wkid 387, sometimes referred to under its old name: wkid 102100). The coordinates for any point of the world fall into the following range:

```
Xmin: -20037700  XMax: 20037700   // easting
Ymin: -30241100  YMax: 30241100   // northing
```